# property 'database' does not exist on type 'firebaseapp' ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement real-time database of firebase to my typescript react app, base on this Medium post: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/todo-app-using-firebase-react-typescript-ea0a34bd417d

In the config step, I got the error property 'database' does not exist on type 'firebaseapp' ts(2339)

[image: image of error]

I searched for the error but cannot find the answer, can anyone help ?
this is my first time i ask something so if my question make any inconvenient for you i'm sorry, thank you guys a lot for your help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firebase recently released the [new Modular SDK V9](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) which has improved performance and at the same time uses a new syntax. Most of the old tutorials follow `V8` and if you want to follow them change the imports to `compat` version:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/database'
// import 'firebase/compat/[SERVICE]'
```

However, I would highly recommend to upgrade to new syntax and follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) which has examples of both `V8` and `V9`. The new syntax looks like:

```ts
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app' // no compat for new SDK
import { getDatabase, ref } from 'firebase/database'

const config = {...}

const app = initializeApp(config)

const database = getDatabase(app)

export const todosRef = ref(database, "todos")
```

Comment: this works for me, really appreciate your help